# Как найти совпадение по шаблону(картинке) в определённой области на экране(с какой то координаты до другой)

Tags: python, шаблоны

Я хочу найти совпадение на экране, то есть не делая скриншоты и после того как совпадение было найдено выполнялось какое то действие.

Я уже пробовал искать, но не нашёл.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: с помощью pyautogui можно

Comment: Это я знаю, НО КАК, можете отправить примерный код и как настроить процент совпадения.

Comment: хм окей с opencv пойдет? чтоб искал совпадение изображения (шаблона) в определенной области на экране с координатами